# Warning: imageftbbox(): Invalid font filename in C:\...\Classes\pChart.class on line 556, 566, 576, 583, 606, 613, 633, 3329, 3340

Tags: php, xampp, pchart

So I am getting multiple error messages on my webpage;

```
Warning: imagettftext(): Invalid font filename in on line C:\...\Classes\pChart.class 556, 566, 576, 583, 606, 613, 633, 3329, 3340
```

Here I am setting the path on my php file, but the error is in the class.php (downloaded from pChart)

```
$path = config::get("framework")."classes/pChart/";
$Test->setFontProperties($path . "Fonts/tahoma.ttf",10);[/code]
```

I did find this under installation but don't quite understand it as I believe that is what I did above?

All the ttf files must be accessible from your web scripts, you may need to update the path of the default font using the setFontProperties function :

```
1.$myPicture->setFontProperties(array("FontName"=>"/home/var/fonts/myfont.ttf");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the full path? It is possible that it is not correct, try to show it.

Maybe the line `$path = config::get("framework")."classes/pChart/";` needs a slash.

Comment: After echoing out the path, it is correct (with the slash as `config::get("framework")` returns the path with a /.

`C:/Users/user1/Documents/the/server/path/framework/classes/pChart/`

Comment: Ok, then try to do like the example with an array:  `$myPicture->setFontProperties(array("FontName"=>$path . "Fonts/tahoma.ttf","FontSize"=>10));`

Comment: This gives me more errors, however they are different! `Warning: imageftbbox() expects parameter 3 to be string, array given in C:\Users\user1\Documents\the\server\path\framework\classes\pChart\Classes\pChart.class on line 556`

Comment: Read the documentation. I saw the first var ($FontName) must be in the current path like your initial code. Sorry but i don't know how to fix it. http://pchart.sourceforge.net/documentation.php?topic=pChart#